# How to upload and store attachment on MySQL database

Tags: 22.04, mysql

I'm somewhat skilled at making Microsoft Access databases, but not experienced with MySQL.  I have a Access database project that I want to convert to a MySQL database with a Access frontend.  Eventually, though, I want the frontend to be a web app, but I'm not that experienced yet.

Anyway, I installed a Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 with MySQL installed.  I created a database with three tables so far.  I exported three of my Access tables to the MySQL server database.  In one of the tables, I want to store barcodes for our organization's asset database.  My goal is to be able to upload the barcodes to the MySQL server and save the file path in one of the fields.

Is there anyone willing to help me figure this out?

Comment: So probably not a great fit with AU, you might get better help with this issue on Stack Overflow...